# Setting up Postgres: Can't connect remotely to Postgres server

Tags: postgresql

I am having a problem getting postgres to accept connections from my other server. Here's my setup:

- **APP06** (10.55.129.31): Server running Postgres
- **APP05** (10.55.129.30): Server trying to connect to Postgres

Here's my `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` file on **app06**:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         10.55.129.30/32       trust
host    all         all         10.55.129.31/32       trust
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0             trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
```

It's not exactly what I want (I'd like to use LDAP), but it should at least work. I want to connect 10.55.129.30 to 10.44.129.31. The first `host` line should be all I need. The third `host` line should allow a connection from anywhere.

Now, we start up Postgres on **app06**

```
 $ /etc/init.d/postgres start
 $ /etc/init.d/postgres status

 pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 30091)
 /usr/bin/postgres "-D" "/var/lib/pgsql/data"
```

Looks good...

Let's look at Netstat:

```
$ netstat -nlp | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      30091/postmaster    
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16490154 30091/postmaster    /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Okay... I think... Not being a real system administrator, I can't say exactly what that means, but it looks like PID 30091 (process postmaster) has port 5432 open.

Let's see if anything is listening on port 5432

```
$ telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Okay, Port 5432 is open and accepting connections.

Now, we'll go to APP05 and see if we can connect...

I've already tried running `psql` from **app05** with no success. Can I talk to **app06**?

```
$ ping app06

PING app06 (10.55.129.31) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from app06 (10.55.129.31): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.901 ms
64 bytes from app06 (10.55.129.31): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.230 ms

--- app06 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5001ms
```

Okay, I can talk to app06 from app05. Let's see if I can connect to Postgres' port:

```
$ telnet app06 5432
Trying 10.55.129.31...
telnet: connect to address 10.55.129.31: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I'm not able to connect to port 5432

I ran `/usr/sbin/lokkit` and verified that the software firewall is turned off.

I'm not a network or system administrator by any means. I am not a postgres administrator either. It's very possible I missed some simple, stupid thing, but I don't know what.

I'm pretty sure that Port 5432 on these machines are open on the network. I tried switching the Postgres port to 8999 which I sure is not blocked, but I get the same issue.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open postgresql.conf in a text editor and look for the `listen_addresses` keyword. Set it to `*`

Restart pgsql.

Comment: how could I add more IP address

Answer (score 6):

Just FYI ... one *incredibly dumb* thing that I nevertheless did was to forget to remove the leading "**#**" in the "listen_addresses" line in the configuration file when I went to change it.  (Yep... therefore, the line was [still] a *comment!*  Duh-h-h-hhh.)

Comment: Just spend 2 hours and this was my mistake LOL, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

the answer is very simple, your postgress installation is binded to 127.0.0.1 interface only

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      30091/postmaster
```

you need to reconfigure it and bind it to your network interface / IP address and you'll be able to access

Answer (score 0):

Just let some body who met the same problem:

1. I am sure postgres is running pretty well in local.
2. I can visit and operate postgres in my local.  ( 192.168.10.14)
3. I am sure all the config items are correct ( listening to '*' , and allow 0.0.0.0/0 to visit )
4. I can telenet postgres from another PC. ( 192.168.10.20) , however can not connect postgres.

```
   telnet 192.168.10.14 5432   # ->  OK
   ping 192.168.10.14          # ->  OK
   psql -h 192.168.10.14       # ->  failed.  remote server closed ...
```

4. finally I got the answer： I incorrectly setup my network.  the network mask should be `255.255.255.0`, but not `0.0.0.0` :

```
# correct mask: 
255.255.255.0

# incorrect mask
0.0.0.0
```

5. so I corrected the network-mask of my network, restart, everything goes well!